# Nginx reverse proxy causing infinite loop

Tags: redirect, nginx, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, redirect-loop

I have the following in my Nginx site config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost/page-1/;
    }
}
```

The issue only seems to occur when I add the `proxy_set_header Host $host;` line. It appears that the `$host` variable creates a redirect loop and the GET request from the error server logs goes something like this `...page-1/page-1/page-1/page-1...` with the server responding with an internal error 500.

I'd be really grateful if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: And what did you expect?

Comment: I expected example2.com to show http://localhost/page-1/. Do you know why it is not working?

Comment: Then you should not set Host header

Comment: Why, what is the Host header for then? All the examples I've seen include it.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html read how nginx processes your request. In your case, including `Host` cause proxy request to fall into the same server block.

Comment: Thanks, if you submit this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Should I still be using the `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;` and `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` lines?

Comment: It depends on your needs, but probably you should

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and as suggested by Alexey Ten, the solution is to remove the Host header.