# Nginx proxy subdomain to laravel url

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, proxy, laravel-5

I'm trying to reverse proxy using nginx from subdomain to url served by Laravel (version 5.2). In my top domain (domain.com) it's served on url `domain.com/sub`. I want it accesible by domain `sub.domain.com`. It should proxy `sub.domain.com` to serve same thing with `domain.com/sub`. Here's my nginx conf for reverse proxy

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://domain.com/sub;
    }
}
```

Here's my nginx conf for laravel app

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # Useful logs for debug.
    access_log      /var/www/domain/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/domain/error.log;
    rewrite_log     on;

    root /var/www/domain/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.com local.domain;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

But it returned `500 internal server error`. Any suggestion to fix it or how to achieve that? Thanks :)

Comment: Error 500 means the error is in the application. Could you share the error stack trace? Inside the log files.

Comment: Hmm, i don't think it's in application. Because it works as usual, if I access it from `domain.com/sub`

But let me check its log

Comment: Nginx error log, then.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ans-4175/52f9fea034a92e2e3e494998bffb9b6e
There's error log

I have 2 nginx.conf, one for laravel app conf and other is the proxy conf.
I thought that it was loop from proxy to app. Hmm

Comment: Try to add trailing slash to the proxy_pass url; `http://domain.com/sub/`

Comment: same output, still like loop redirect.

Comment: may I know your sub is a folder or a route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it's problem and solution from here
[Nginx reverse proxy causing infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362396/nginx-reverse-proxy-causing-infinite-loop)

Looks like I set proxy_header host, thats what created loop. So I commented proxy_header host. Here's my full conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass         http://domain.com/sub;
    }
}
```