# Nginx - Infinite reload when adding variable in proxy_pass

Tags: loops, docker, nginx, static, reload

I am working with Nginx on Docker and I want to assign each user to a different port.

First, without adding anything, my code works fine:

```
    location  /viewer/ {
        proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:18080/Road/;
    }
```

Going to "/viewer/" in URL will proxy to the port 18080, just as expected.

But if I add any variable to the proxy_pass like:

```
set $test 1;
proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:18080/Road/?$test;
```

then, first of all, the static files do not load anymore and I have to add lines like these:

```
    location ~ \.css {
       add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }
    location ~ \.js {
       add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
    }
```

After this, the static files work again but the page starts to reload infinitely.

Before I was thinking it was because I replaced the port by a variable in proxy_pass, but as I showed you it happens when I add any variable there.

What do you think I could do wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you use `Host Headers`? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362396/nginx-reverse-proxy-causing-infinite-loop

Comment: Hi. I saw this post before but I am not using Host Headers in this location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a variable to `proxy_pass` changes it's behaviour. You will need to construct the entire URI.

In your original configuration, the URI `/viewer/foo` is translated to `/Road/foo` before passing upstream.

In your new configuration, the URI `/viewer/foo` is translated to `/Road/?1` and the tail of the original URI is lost.

You may have more success using `rewrite...break` to modify the URI.

For example:

```
location  /viewer/ {
    rewrite ^/viewer(.*)$ /road$1?something break;
    proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:18080;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

---

According to your comment, you wish to change the destination port.

For example:

```
location  /viewer/ {
    rewrite ^/viewer(.*)$ /road$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:$myport;
}
```

If you specify the upstream server by IP address, a `resolver` statement will not be required. But if you specify the upstream by name, you will need to define a `resolver`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) for details.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. This works fine with the example variable $test I used up there.
But if I want to replace the port by a variable, like "$port" instead of "18080", then the problem will be the same. I still find no way to proxy a port for each user.
I think it's very weird how proxy_pass changes its behavior just by adding a variable...