# Nginx remove location path with upstream variable

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've installed a nginx reverse proxy on Docker for send trafic to my front-end or backend depending on the URI.

I'm using the **$upstream** variable for lunching the nginx deamon even if one of my container is down (I need to access to my API even if the frontend is down).
I also need to remove the `/api` or `/ui` part.

But I've a problem with the redirection to my real webserver. I've added the trailing slash (/) at the end of the `proxy_pass` line, but it does not solve my issue (according to this SO https://serverfault.com/a/586614)

`https://test.com/ui/test/index2.html` send to the root of my webserver : `app:80 172.18.0.4 - - [12/Dec/2019:15:38:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 996 "-" "curl/7.47.0"`

`https://test.com/ui/` have the same behaviour as before, which is not normal : `app:80 172.18.0.4 - - [12/Dec/2019:15:39:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 996 "-" "curl/7.47.0"`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;

}


server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  test.com;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;


    location /ui/ {
        # permet de rediriger le trafic vers le conteneur webapp1
        # meme si il n existe pas
        # attention, le / a la fin est important car il retire la partie location
        set $upstream http://webapp1/;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
    location /api/ {
        set $upstream http://webapp2:5000/;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

}
```

I tried to change the config to this :

```
    location /ui/ {
        proxy_pass http://webapp1/;;
    }
```

And it works well, so the upstream change the behavior of the redirection

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163580/nginx-infinite-reload-when-adding-variable-in-proxy-pass/58164232#58164232)

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith. It's working