# Dynamic proxy_pass according request header in Nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Here is part of my `nginx.conf`:

```
    location ^~ /api/ {
        #resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s; #don't work
        resolver 10.244.64.10;
        set $loadurl http://gateway-service.default.svc.cluster.local:55558/;
        if ($http_namespace != "" ) {
            set $loadurl http://gateway-service.$http_namespace.svc.cluster.local:55558/;
        }
        proxy_pass $loadurl;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $proxy_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cookie_path / /;  
    }
```

The Nginx is running on Kubernetes.
I'm trying to configure `proxy_pass` according to the `namespace` in the header.

Such as:
When I request `http://localhost/api/auth/login` with header `namespace:test`,
I want `proxy_pass` is `http://gateway-service.test.svc.cluster.local:55558/auth/login`.

Or header namespace is empty, then `proxy_pass` is `http://gateway-service.default.svc.cluster.local:55558/auth/login`

But now I always get 404, I'm confused!

So I try the below test,
Using a variable in ```proxy_pass`` is not working, I also got 404:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    resolver 10.244.64.10;
    set $loadurl http://gateway-service.default.svc.cluster.local:55558/;
    proxy_pass $loadurl; 
}
```

When I write URI in `proxy_pass`, Nginx can proxy the request to the default namespace, and I got the right response:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://gateway-service.default.svc.cluster.local:55558/; 
}
```

I stuck here for almost three days. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to remove the trailing `/` and add a `rewrite...break`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163580/nginx-infinite-reload-when-adding-variable-in-proxy-pass/58164232#58164232).

Answer (score 1):

@RichardSmith comment helped me!I should use `rewrite`.
The configeration below work fine for me.

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local; #It working
    if ($http_namespace != "" ) {
        rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://gateway-service.$http_namespace.svc.cluster.local:55558;
        break;
    }
    proxy_pass http://gateway-service.default.svc.cluster.local:55558/;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cookie_path / /;  
}
```

And `resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;` also working in kubernetes!